# Filtering objects with null property on Realm for React Native

Tags: database, react-native, realm

React Native and Realm noob here!

I want to load objects where one particular property is null.

I tried to filter them like this:

```
let goals = Modal.objects('goal').filtered('SubGoalOf == $0', null);
```

I've also tried this:

```
let goals = Modal.objects('goal').filtered('SubGoalOf == $0', {});
```

But got errors like "Value is not an object" and "object is not Realm Object". Query without filtered method is working perfectly and returning everything. But that's not exactly what I am going for.

This would be the schema:

```
Goal.schema = {
  name: 'goal',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    createdOn: 'date',
    itemName: {type: 'string', indexed: true },
    SubGoalOf: {type: 'goal', optional: true},
    ShouldNotify: 'bool',
    WhenNotify: {type:'date', optional: true},
    deadline: {type:'date', optional: true},
    isComplete: 'bool',
    completedOn: {type:'date', optional: true},
  }
}
```

It would be great, if anyone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Realm React Native doesn't support querying for `null`. This enhancement is tracked by this issue:

> Implement/test null queries for all optional types

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/162

Comment: Update: It currently *does* support this in version >= `0.12.0`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter an answer on the question would be great then?!

Comment: @regetskcob You're welcome to do it. It's been two and a half years since I made this comment so my context has been lost.